# How to reset the frequency to 50Hz on a Wii that has been set to 60Hz, without a TV supporting 60Hz?

Tags: nintendo-wii, monitor

I changed the settings of a Wii to 60Hz, and I can't reset it to 50Hz since the displaying on my TV does not support 60Hz.

I have read over the internet that there is a manipulation that can be done by pressing the down button on a Wii controller while resetting the Wii.

It does not work for me. Is there an another workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset the Wii to 50Hz press reset on the Wii while pressing down on the directional pad on the wiimote.

[source](http://linuxjunk.blogspot.com/2007/06/wii-50hz-reset.html)

Comment: It is the trick that I mentioned in my post... And that did not work for me... Does the "down" button is the one when the Wii controller is horizontal or the one when the controller is vertical ?

Comment: @Xavier I'm pretty sure when holding it vertically with the eye pointed at the wii, down is towards you.  I have found significant evidence to suggest this works and is the commonly accepted solution.  Perhaps your problem may be something else?  Could you post the symptoms (whats wrong with your picture etc) if that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm also having the same (I believe) issue. I have my Wii hooked up to an LG 24" computer monitor via the Neoya Wii2HDMI device, I'm getting the error "HDMI Out of range 15.6 khz / 50 hz" when I turn on my wii. resetting with down held down did nothing.